# sql loop with id, date, and 1 additional field (in redshift)

Tags: sql, loops, amazon-redshift

The scenario is:
A patient is taking multiple medications (denoted by ndc)
Each medication has a fill date with a corresponding fill_nbr.
eg: each ndc has fill_nbr = 1 as the initial fill.
NDCs may or not have refills: fill_nbr = 2 is the 2nd fill (or 1st refill) , fill_nbr = 3 is the 3rd fill (or 2nd refill), etc.

I need the datediff between each fill_nbr and the next fill_nbr for each ndc - by patient.
If there is no refill, the days_between_refills should be 0.

Using dbeaver/redshift.

The end result needs to look like this:

```
| patient_id |  rx_date  | fill_nbr |    ndc     | days_between_refills |
|   654654   | 01/13/2021|    1     | 1565475214 |          0           |      
|   654654   | 01/18/2021|    2     | 1565475214 |          5           |
|   654654   | 01/21/2021|    3     | 1565475214 |          3           |
|   654654   | 02/02/2022|    1     | 2449499446 |          0           |
|   654654   | 02/09/2022|    2     | 2449499446 |          7           |
|   654654   | 02/19/2022|    3     | 2449499446 |         10           |
|   654654   | 02/29/2022|    4     | 2449499446 |          9           |
|   832156   | 03/01/2020|    1     | 3489446548 |          0           |
|   832156   | 03/12/2020|    2     | 3489446548 |         12           |
|   832156   | 03/20/2020|    3     | 3489446548 |          8           |
|   832156   | 03/26/2020|    4     | 3489446548 |          6           |
```

The 2 issues I would like to solve are:

1.
loop by patient_id/ndc

2.
all datediff numbers in 1 column: "days_between_fill"

```
this script works:

t1.ndc,DATEDIFF(day,t1.rx_date,t2.rx_date) as days_between_fill
FROM sandbox.table1 t1
INNER JOIN
sandbox.table2 t2
on
t1.ndc = t2.ndc
WHERE 
t1.patient_id = t2.patient_id 
and
t1.fill_nbr  = 1 and t2.fill_nbr  = 2
```

but it needs a loop by patientid/ndc as there are many patients with >200 refills of the same ndc

```
and I do **NOT** want to write this 200+ times...

t1.fill_nbr  = 1 and t2.fill_nbr  = 2
t1.fill_nbr  = 2 and t2.fill_nbr  = 3
t1.fill_nbr  = 3 and t2.fill_nbr  = 4

etc.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *,   lag(rx_date, 1) over (partition by patient_id, ndc order by fill_nbr) as last_refill_date , coalesce(datediff(day, lag(rx_date, 1) over (partition by patient_id, ndc order by fill_nbr), rx_date), 0) as days_between_refills from table order by 1, 2, 3 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need to solve this by `LAG` function.

Please check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html) example.

```sql
select buyerid, saletime, qtysold,
lag(qtysold,1) over (order by buyerid, saletime) as prev_qtysold
from sales where buyerid = 3 order by buyerid, saletime;
```

| buyerid | saletime | qtysold | prev_qtysold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2008-01-16 01:06:09 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2008-01-28 02:10:01 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-03-12 10:39:53 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-03-13 02:56:07 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-03-29 08:21:39 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-04-27 02:39:01 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2008-08-16 07:04:37 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-08-22 11:45:26 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2008-09-12 09:11:25 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2008-10-01 06:22:37 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-10-20 01:55:51 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-10-28 01:30:40 | 1 | 2 |

---

**UPDATE 2023-01-18**

```sql
SELECT patient_id, rx_date, fill_nbr, ndc,
    (CASE WHEN ( 
                patient_id = lag(patient_id, 1) over (order by patient_id, ndc, rx_date) AND 
                ndc = lag(ndc, 1) over (order by patient_id, ndc, rx_date) 
            ) THEN 
                date_diff('day', lag(rx_date, 1) over (order by patient_id, ndc, rx_date), rx_date)
         ELSE 0
    END) AS days_between_refills
FROM (    
    VALUES 
    (654654, date_parse('01/13/2021', '%m/%d/%Y'), 1, 1565475214),
    (654654, date_parse('01/18/2021', '%m/%d/%Y'), 2, 1565475214),
    (654654, date_parse('01/21/2021', '%m/%d/%Y'), 3, 1565475214),
    (654654, date_parse('02/02/2022', '%m/%d/%Y'), 1, 2449499446),
    (654654, date_parse('02/09/2022', '%m/%d/%Y'), 2, 2449499446),
    (654654, date_parse('02/19/2022', '%m/%d/%Y'), 3, 2449499446),
    (654654, date_parse('02/28/2022', '%m/%d/%Y'), 4, 2449499446),
    (832156, date_parse('03/01/2020', '%m/%d/%Y'), 1, 3489446548),
    (832156, date_parse('03/12/2020', '%m/%d/%Y'), 2, 3489446548),
    (832156, date_parse('03/20/2020', '%m/%d/%Y'), 3, 3489446548),
    (832156, date_parse('03/26/2020', '%m/%d/%Y'), 4, 3489446548)
) AS t (patient_id, rx_date, fill_nbr, ndc)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
654654 2021-01-13 00:00:00.000 1 1565475214 0
654654 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 2 1565475214 5
654654 2021-01-21 00:00:00.000 3 1565475214 3
654654 2022-02-02 00:00:00.000 1 2449499446 0
654654 2022-02-09 00:00:00.000 2 2449499446 7   
654654 2022-02-19 00:00:00.000 3 2449499446 10
654654 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 4 2449499446 9
832156 2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 1 3489446548 0
832156 2020-03-12 00:00:00.000 2 3489446548 11
832156 2020-03-20 00:00:00.000 3 3489446548 8
832156 2020-03-26 00:00:00.000 4 3489446548 6
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response!   The lag works as you proviede :) But how do I get the datediff, please?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

Comment: thanks again! :) I already have the datediff working - I need the lag and datediff to work together :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the query :

```
with cte1 as (select *, lag(rx_date,1,rx_date)over(partition by
 patient_id,ndc ) as previous_date  from  table1 ) select *,
rx_date-previous_date as days_between_refills  from cte1;
```

there is not a 29 in february 2022, the max date is 28/02/2022

[image]

Comment: hi  @ei.mensi: thank you so much for chiming in to help me!!!!   :)     I get an error with your script:  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: Default parameter not be supported for window function lag.  I was able to get a script that works which I will post here for the benefit of others

Comment: hi sherri, i attached a picture to my script, it works perfectly.
could you please share the DDL of your table

Comment: wow @ei.mens ! the patient id and ndc in my table is varchar. otherwise the same. would that make a difference?

Comment: not at all sir, it works normally
But if that is the issue in your side you can cast them to integer just put in front of ndc and patient id ::integer

Comment: sounds good @ei.men thanks so much for your help! in the meantime, I also posted the code that worked for me with no error in case someone can use it.